# Modified German Tank problem involving string distance metrics

Tags: probability, estimation, frequency, puzzle

Pretend we have a list of items, e.g. names, and we know it is sorted ALPHANUMERICALLY let's say in ascending order. Given a small set of the first K items, how can we estimate the length of the full list?

E.g.: for K=5:

The subset:

1. Adrian
2. Anna
3. Carl
4. Derrick
5. Eric
   ...

would probably be from a shorter list than the subset:

1. Aaron
2. Adaline
3. Adam
4. Aden
5. Alma

since the average alphanumeric distance between names is a lot less in the 2nd subset than the first subset, and since we know there is the same potential finite length for each full list (there is a last possible name, since the last name on the list will start with Z and be something like Zebulon, etc.).

I can think of 2 approaches.

1. Use average alphanumeric distance between the items of the subset to estimate the full length, e.g. using some metric like Hamming distance or better, Levenshtein distance.
2. Also include priors by using known name frequencies (a lot more complicated, but probably provides a better estimate).

So, can someone please help me to decide on a way to estimate N, the cardinality of the full list, given a subset of the first K names in the alphanumerically sorted list?

Comment: Are you willing to specialize to a given language? Even so, this could turn out to be a hard problem. For example, consider what might happen if your list of names comes from a certain demographic, e.g., transliterated names from some Asian languages. One analogous idea is the $\mathrm{MinCount}$ algorithm which uses the $K$th order statistic of (ideally) *hashed* values. One advantage is that with an ideal hash, you would no longer need to rely on knowledge of the underlying distribution of the data. (There are also more sophisticated ideas like HyperLogLog and its variants.)